# Trouble displaying Circle plus (⊕) in PDF generated using MigraDoc

Tags: c#, migradoc

When generating a PDF, the ⊕ symbol is not displayed, but the replacement symbol is displayed instead of it. Is it possible to work around this problem somehow?

**Versions tested:**

- 1.32
- 1.5 beta 3

**Fonts tested:**

- Arial
- Verdana
- Lucida Console
- Consolas

**Code**

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
var doc = new Document();
doc.Styles["Normal"].Font.Name = "Consolas";

doc.AddSection().AddParagraph("A ⊕ B");

var pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);
pdfRenderer.Document = doc;
pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();
pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(fileName);

Process.Start(fileName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a font that contains the character "Circled Plus".

You can use e.g. "Segoe UI Symbol". "Segoe UI" does not contain that character.

MS Word switches the fonts automatically when such symbols are used, with MigraDoc you have to switch the font as needed.

If you want to use "Consolas" for the rest of the text, use `AddFormattedText` for the Circled Plus and switch to e.g. "Segoe UI Symbol" for this symbol.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that auto font substitution applies to a lot of programs/controls in `Windows`, because I used `Notepad` to test if it displayed ⊕, and it surely did. Should have used `Character Map` instead. Lesson learned. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try to replace

```
doc.AddSection().AddParagraph("A ⊕ B");
```

With:

```
doc.AddSection().AddParagraph("A \u2295 B");
```

Comment: Those are the exact same strings, so that doesn't make a difference.